# How to create multiple block in drupal sharethis

Tags: drupal-modules

I have install new module of sharethis, after configure this module, after that I need to display sharethis block at two places at same page. For that I have create new block instance using multiblock and place this two block in same page.

But Original block is rendered in that page, but block instance create by multiblock module is not displayed. So would try to render this using custom code but it is not working. Please give me solution if u have.

Answer (score 0):

Try multiblock or ctools block plugin to create a second block.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/node/2666664

Comment: Can you explain your answer please ? Only-link answers are mean bad quality for Stack Overflow.